# Login from registration app failed in CSRF verification

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-registration

I'm trying to use Django-registration, but I'm getting this error for login:

```
Forbidden (403)
CSRF verification failed. Request aborted.
```

This is my form:

```
  <form action="." method="post" class="login_form">{% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <p class="submit"><button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit" name="submit" value="Login">Log in</button></p>



    {% if next %}<input type="hidden" name="next" value="{{ next }}">
    {% else %}<input type="hidden" name="next" value="/">
    {% endif %}
  </form>
```

My settings:

```
MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that you are passing back the context from your view

return render_to_response('contact.html', {'form': form},context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Comment: But, where should I put this? Because I don't have a view for login, I'm using the standard from django-registration

Comment: Just wanted to confirm this, you asked this for login form right? If it is for the login form then you will have to setup your own urls login pages

Comment: https://github.com/michaelarshinov/django_simple_backend_user_model Must serve as a good starting point to get this working